# Trying to solve world 3: A Tingling, but can't access 8x time reverse

Tags: linux, braid

I'm trying to solve world 3-8: A Tingling on Braid under linux.  I watched a walkthrough and it showed using 8x time reverse to get back to the beginning before the platform has moved too far.

In my Linux version of Braid, I can't get 8x time reverse to work.  If I hold the shift and press up arrow a few times then the screen turns dark and it says "8x" but nothing happens.

Does anybody know how to make this work?

Comment: Good question! Nice to see that you've already done some research.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, cause it works fine for me. I have Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, and it is a standalone (not Steam) version of Braid. On the other hand, I tried to "collect" (I have already collected the pieces, so I just "tagged" the silouettes) the puzzle pieces without using 8x reverse. It is actually possible.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit rather than 64 bit.  Don't know if that would make a difference.  (I'm thinking I'll install 64 bit when 14.04 comes out; maybe that'll fix my problem?)  I installed Braid by itself from the package center.  But you say it's possible to get the pieces in "A Tingling" with only 1x time reverse?  How do you do that?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to solve the level without high speed time reverse.  But I did figure this out:  it is the *down* arrow that activates the fast time reverse, not the up arrow.  I guess the up arrow must activate fast forward?  Having figured this out, I had no problems in solving the level.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the commentors, I can confirm that tapping the <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow will move you back in time, and tapping the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow will move you forward. (As long as you are holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, you can switch between using fast-forward and fast-backward as often as you like -- when you let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, fast-forward can no longer be used, since the game is already progressing forward at 1x).

My version of Braid also does what yours is doing: when I hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow a few times, the screen will turn dark and it says "8x" but nothing happens. Just keep holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow a few times, and you'll start moving in reverse.